# java Interpretation correct

Tags: java, class

I have the below question, and would like to know if I have interpreted the question right or not. I am new to the Java and programming so the technical terms even thought I read my textbook and understood them I am not sure that if I have programmed them correctly. Please see the question and let me know if what I am doing is in the right direction.

[image]

The question itself:

```
You are asked to implement a class to keep track of the students' academic result for a module. The system requires the following information about a student:
 Student identification - a unique 7-digit identification that begins with 'S' for local students and 'F' for foreign student. E.g. S1234567.
 Student name
 Quiz mark - an integer number in the range of 0 to 100
 Assignment mark - an integer number in the range of 0 to 100
 Exam mark - a floating point number in the range of 0 to 100
 Resit student - true if the student is retaking the paper, false otherwise. Resit student does not have quiz and assignment marks.
Write a Java class called Student and provide the following:
 suitable instance variables for the information described above
 constructor(s) with the appropriate actions on the instance variables
 the accessor methods for the instance variables
 the computeScore() method to compute the score as follows:
for resit students, take only the exam mark as the score
for other students, score is calculated by using the formula
9% * quiz + 21% * assignment + 70% * exam
The score calculated is to be rounded up to the nearest integer and returned.
 the findGrade() method that returns the grade based on the score:

Score range
Grade
80 to 100
A
70 to 79
B
60 to 69
C
50 to 59
D
0 to 49
F
 the toString() method that returns the attribute values as a string with description.
```

then this is the code i have so far is that correct? i mean the way i declared the constructors and such...tks

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package student_qn4;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class Student 
{
   private String student_idno, student_name;
   private int mark_quiz, mark_assig;
   private float mark_exam;
   private boolean student_resit;


   public Student (String id, String name , int quizM , int assignM , int examM) {

 studentId = id;
 studentName = name;
 quizMark = quizM;
 assignMark = assignM;
 examMark = examM;
 }

   public void setStudentnumber(String number)
   {
       student_idno = number;
   }

   public String getStudentnumber()
   {
       return student_idno;
   }

   public void setStudentname(String name)
   {
       student_name = name;
   }

   public String getStudentname()
   {
       return student_name;
   }

    public void setquizMark(int quizmarks)
   {
       mark_quiz = quizmarks;
   }

   public int getquizMark()
   {
       return mark_quiz;
   }


    public void setassigMark(int assigmarks)
   {
       mark_assig = assigmarks;
   }

   public int getassigMark()
   {
       return mark_assig;
   }


   public int computerScore()
   {
       /*do as the program asks then return the computer score */



   }



   public String findGrade()
   {
       // Based on the computeScore() I have to access what is the grade and return that
   }

   public String toString()
   {
       // What is this method supposed to do?
   }

}
```

Comment: haha asked a first question and got that -ve... such a looser me.. is it just me or stackoverflow is not helping begining programmer

Comment: Your question covers quite simple notions of OOP, there are tons of examples and sources that can help you to improve your code. So don't expect upvotes for that kind of questions. For me, I have so much free time to answer you.

Comment: Hint: the string "-ve" is not a word in the English language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

generally ok, if you take on board the comments made in the other answer.

However, your naming conventions are a bit wacky. Standard java bean convention is to name your properties (your ints and so on) with camelCase (so markQuiz rather than mark_quiz) and your getters and setters as getMarkQuiz and setMarkQuiz (the 1st letter after get/set is now capitalized) For boolean properties, use isXxx() rather than getXxx().

These conventions are widely used and will make your code more tool friendly (with ides such as ecliipse/netbeans)

Regards to your comment after your question, homework questions are generally frowned upon, which is why you got down voted. You will learn far more by playing and experimenting, getting it wrong and then fixing it, than by coming here asking for an answer. At least you did provide a skeleton answer, so you are thinking about it, so well done for that.Keep at it!

Comment: thanks and +1 for pointing camelCase notation, I totally forgot it to point in my answer since I haven't coded in Java for a year or two.

Comment: +1 for the naming convention. This link on ["Java Programming Style Guide"](http://www.cwu.edu/~gellenbe/javastyle/naming.html) might come in handy!

Comment: Tks for the support and tks for pointing in the right direction. I managed to complete my assignment finally.